# Use Excel Formulas to Populate Cells with Names of Sheets in Other Workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for a way to populate a column in a spreadsheet with the names of sheets in another workbook. The source workbook's name is `Report.xlsx` and it is formatted such that the sheet names are employee names (i.e. `Doe, John`) and each sheet has a constant range that I am interested in using (let's call it `A1:A20` for the sake of this example).

The source workbook is located on my company's network, so I need to be able to reference the workbook via network path. If I have a column of cells whose values are the sheet names in that workbook, I can concatenate the workbook name with the sheet name in individual rows, then concatenate that string with the range I want to reference.

How can I use an Excel formula to gather the list of sheet names from a network-mapped workbook and populate a column with those values? I cannot use VBA due to employer restrictions.

Comment: Keeping the sole master list of employees as the worksheets in a workbook doesn't seem like the best way to do things.

Comment: It's the only output I get from my workplace's database management system. It generates a workbook of information pertaining to individual employees, and it stores each employee's information in a worksheet named after that employee.

Comment: @Jeeped You have misinterpreted my question. The sole master list of employees is not contained as names of worksheets in a workbook. I do, however, have workbooks whose sheets are named after different subsets of employees.